# sorting the column of csv file through an element (scores) without using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting

I'm having trouble sorting the scores on my data without using pandas. Here's my code below:

```py
def loadData():
    fileHandle = open('Leaderboard.csv', 'r')
    player = {}
    for line in fileHandle:
        data = line[0:-1].split(",")
        playerName = data[0]
        playerScore = data[1]
        playerPattern = data[2]
        playerData = {}
        playerData["Score"] = playerScore
        playerData["Pattern"] = playerPattern
        player[playerName] = playerData
    fileHandle.close()
    return player

    def leaderboard(player):
        print("=========================================")
        print("              LEADERBOARD")
        for k in player:
            playerData = player[k]
            playerScore = playerData["Score"]
            playerPattern = playerData["Pattern"]
            print(k + " - " + playerScore + " - " + playerPattern)
        print("\n")

player = loadData()
leaderboard(player)
```

**Sample CSV file:**

```
Eman,30,kerf
Hans,10,ie
John,55,okelf
Gian,40,jfue
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
John - 55 - okelf
Gian - 40 - jfue
Eman - 30 - kerf
Hans - 10 - ie
```

*Would really appreciate your help. Thank you!*

Answer (score 0):

I amended your code in a more pythonic way, feel free to use the code snippet below as you like.

The main change that I made is in the `leaderboard` function, from this:

```py
for k in player:
```

to this:

```py
for player_name in sorted(
    all_players.keys(),
    key=lambda x: all_players[x]['Score'],
    reverse=True
):
```

```py
def loadData(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        all_players = {}
        for line in f:
            data = line[0:-1].split(",")
            player_name = data[0]
            player_score = data[1]
            player_pattern = data[2]
            
            player = {}
            player['Score'] = player_score
            player['Pattern'] = player_pattern
            
            all_players[player_name] = player
    return all_players

def leaderboard(all_players):
    print('=========================================')
    print('              LEADERBOARD')
    for player_name in sorted(
        all_players.keys(),
        key=lambda x: all_players[x]['Score'],
        reverse=True
    ):
        player = all_players[player_name]
        player_score = player['Score']
        player_pattern = player['Pattern']
        print(f'{player_name} - {player_score} - {player_pattern}')
    print()

filename = 'Leaderboard.csv'
all_players = loadData(filename)
leaderboard(all_players)
```

Comment: this works but the sorting becomes like this: (the latest player will be in the first line instead) the score was not sorted